# Repeat many times child: GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart

I created this code but I would like to have 4x4 flip card could you tell me how can I do ? please

Below the code if you can help me thank you.
I would like repeat GestureDetector 4 x 4.
in a new flip_card.dart file.

Below the code if you can help me thank you.
I would like repeat GestureDetector 4 x 4.
in a new flip_card.dart file.

I am beginner if you can explain to me step by step please. thank you.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  bool _flag = true;
  Color _color = Colors.blue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), value: 1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: flip,
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return Transform(
                transform:
                    Matrix4.rotationY((1 - _controller.value) * math.pi / 2),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                  height: 70,
                  width: 70,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: _color.withOpacity(0.2),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                  child: _flag
                      ? Text(
                          'Carte A',
                          textScaleFactor: 1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        )
                      : Image.asset('assets/gold.png'),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void flip() async {
    if (!_flag) {
      return;
    }
    if (_flag) {
      await _controller.reverse();
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.orange;
      });
      await _controller.forward();
    } else {
      await _controller.reverse();
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.blue;
      });
      await _controller.forward();
    }
    setState(() {
      _flag = !_flag;
    });

    Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
      if (_flag) {
        await _controller.reverse();
        setState(() {
          _color = Colors.orange;
        });
        await _controller.forward();
      } else {
        await _controller.reverse();
        setState(() {
          _color = Colors.blue;
        });
        await _controller.forward();
      }

      setState(() {
        _flag = !_flag;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flip_card package](https://pub.dev/packages/flip_card):

**1.** Add the dependency to the `pubspec` dependencies:

```
flip_card: ^0.4.4
```

**2.** Import the package:

```
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';
```

**3.** Make a `GridView` with `crossAxisCount` of 4. This is the number of cards in each row.

**4.** Using `List.generate(16, ...` you can make 16 cards (to make a 4*4 layout).

**5.** Each `FlipCard` has a `front` and a `back`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
          child: GridView.count(
              childAspectRatio: 1.5,
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              children: List.generate(16, (index) {
                return FlipCard(
                  front: Container(
                      height: 70,
                      width: 70,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: _color.withOpacity(0.2),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                      child: Text(
                        'Carte A',
                        textScaleFactor: 1,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )),
                  back: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    width: 70,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: _color.withOpacity(0.2),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/gold.png'),
                  ),
                );
              }))),
    );
  }
```

**Result**:

[image: res]

**Update:** this is a solution to make every card **flip back after two seconds** (based on comments below):

```
  List<GlobalKey<FlipCardState>> keys = [];
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      GlobalKey<FlipCardState> cardKey = new GlobalKey<FlipCardState>();
      keys.add(cardKey);
    }

  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
          child: GridView.count(
              childAspectRatio: 1.5,
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              children: List.generate(16, (index) {
                return FlipCard(
                  key: keys[index],
                  onFlip: () async {
                    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds : 2)) .then((value) => {
                      if (!keys[index].currentState.isFront)
                        keys[index].currentState.toggleCard()
                    });
                  },
                  front: Container(
                      height: 70,
                      width: 70,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: _color.withOpacity(0.2),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                      child: Text(
                        'Carte A',
                        textScaleFactor: 1,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )),
                  back: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    width: 70,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: _color.withOpacity(0.2),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/person.png'),
                  ),
                );
              }))),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello Mobina,

Thank you for you answer and to give me this good solution.
If i can ask you an other question
I would like when I return two card return both automaticly after two seconds.
I dont know if this api can to do it.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: You can store a list of `GlobalKeys` (e.g., `keys`). Every item in this list is a key for a card in the grid. In the `initState` you can make the keys in a loop and add them to the list: `GlobalKey<FlipCardState> cardKey = GlobalKey<FlipCardState>(); keys.add(cardKey);` Then you can set a timer that executes this command for every key in keys: `keys[i].currentState.toggleCard();` after two seconds. @Carle

Comment: Sorry I am beginner I dont know how can I do :(

Comment: Ok I'm gonna add it to my answer. @Carle

Comment: Thank you Mobina for I modified your good sample for yo do when I want but I have an error :(  I dont know how can I add my solution in this space? could you help me please

Comment: Thank you for your solution but now I would like disabled the other card when the two cards aren't return

Comment: That's whole another question. But in short, use `if (keys[key1index].currentState.isFront && keys[key2index].currentState.isFront)`  and inside the `if` body set a variable to true. When this variable is true return a normal card instead of a flip card. @Carle

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to upvote and accept the answers that help you. Good luck! @Carle